# How can we fix the error on running the CosmosDB emulator in local PC?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I try to launch CosmosDB emulator from my windows 7, I am getting the error message 'The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer...'

[image]

Need support to fix this error.

Thanks.

Comment: If the issue is not solved via the below thread ,pease feel free to let me know.

Comment: I get the same error for trying to install PySpice with conda, (for Google search purposes)  I guess it's just not compatible with Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Azure Cosmos DB local emulator is only supported on Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016, or Windows 10. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#system-requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to unsupported OS(Windows 7) for Cosmos DB Emulator.

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#system-requirements